# Unicode characters and subscripts in minted python

Tags: unicode, minted, subscripts, python

using Sympy and print I get the Unicode characters shown below. I am trying to display them in minted. I tried to create the individual characters using *newunicodechar*. This seem to work for π but the subscripts don't: I get the following output

[image]

**My code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{π}{\pi}

\newunicodechar{₀}{\ensuremath{{}_{0}}}

\newunicodechar{₁}{\ensuremath{{}_{1}}}

...

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}

π₀, π₁, t₁

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`  Please don't add ... in places that cause errors

Answer (score 2):

You forgot math mode for pi (there is no problem with the subscripts)

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{π}{\ensuremath{\pi}}

\newunicodechar{₀}{\ensuremath{{}_{0}}}

\newunicodechar{₁}{\ensuremath{{}_{1}}}


\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}

π₀, π₁, t₁

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the  red boxes are not a tex issue, pygments styles them as a python error in this context.

Comment: Thank you! How can I remove the red boxes?

Comment: my python is a bit rusty here, but assuming that's valid python, the proper way would be to report a bug in pygments python lexer. a quick fix in the `_minted-...` folder for your document, copy `default.pygstyle` to `my.pygstyle` and change one line to `\@namedef{PYG@tok@err}{\def\PYG@bc##1{##1}}`  (removing the red box) then add  `\usemintedstyle[python]{my}` to your document. Makes [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLU96.png)